# Understanding mathematical syntax in SO(3)

Tags: education, mathematical-modeling

In this [paper](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~mleok/pdf/LeLeMc2010_quadrotor.pdf), pp. 2, I found the following differential equation system and a statement:

[image: Taken from the paper]

There are two things not clear to me:

1. the *hat map* symbol seems to make mathematical symbolics shorter and hat the same meanign as a cross product between two vectors (if I understand it correctly). Ok, but the only hat map I can see is on the Matrix: $\hat{\Omega}$. So what cross product should I consider?!?!?
2. is the *hat map* really a short way to mean a cross product between vectors?!? Since I m not a mathematical student, I m not sure. Usually you use it in engineering field like a "index" for not repeating the same letter in the text;

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second question:

For any vector $x$ in 3-space, there is a map on $\mathbb R^3$ that sends $y \mapsto x \times y$. That map is linear, and it's sometimes useful to be able to talk about the *map* rather than the value of the linear map on some particular vector $y$. So the author has given the map a name -- $\hat{x}$. To make it concrete, if $x = [a, b, c]$, then $\hat{x}$ is multiplication by the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -c & b\\
c & 0 & -a\\
-b & a & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For the first: I think that the author is treating the angular velocity $\Omega$ as a 3-component *vector* $(a, b, c)$, and the associated map $\hat{\Omega}$ is therefore "multiplication by the matrix I've written above".