# Understanding mathematical syntax in SO(3) - Part II

Tags: education, mathematical-modeling

In a [paper](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~mleok/pdf/LeLeMc2010_quadrotor.pdf) I found in internet there is a relation about mapping a matrix into a vector and viceversa. One question has been already kindly answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082539/understanding-mathematical-syntax-in-so3?answertab=oldest#tab-top), but since I'm new to this kind of syntax I need more help.

In the paper on the third page the following relation is needed to calculate an error:

$
e_{R} = \frac{1}{2}(R_{d}^{T}R - R^{T}R_{d})^{\vee}
$

which results to be a matrix.
Now my concern is about the $\vee$ operator. Since it is supposed to map back a vector from that matrix, to be more precise $x \times y \mapsto y $ $\in \mathbb{R^{3}}$, I'm a little bit confused on the right way to proceed.

1. At first I thought I could map the matrix back to the sensor simply inverting the way I did it for getting the [matrix from the vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082539/understanding-mathematical-syntax-in-so3/1082548#1082548). I mean, given the matrix 
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -c & b\\
   c & 0 & -a\\
   -b & a & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   I simply copy that components into a vector:
   $x = [a, b, c]$ and that's all;
2. But reading more accurately the paper I found the following statement: "the $\vee$ map is the inverse of the hat map. We used the fact that $-\frac{1}{2}tr[\hat{x}\hat{y}] = x^{T}y$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R^{3}}$"... It suggests me that copying values into a vector is not a smart solution.

Now I'm a little bit confused on which way is better to get that vector from the resulting matrix:

$
\frac{1}{2}(R_{d}^{T}R - R^{T}R_{d}) = ?
$

Thanks

Comment: The "vee" map will map the skew-symmetric matrix shown in your item #1 back to the vector $[a,b,c]$, because it's the inverse of the "hat" map. So, what you had in mind is correct, it seems to me. The "vee" mapping works only when applied to a skew-symmetric matrix; but $e_R$ is skew-symmetric, so all is well.

Comment: mh...I realized a C++ code for that algorithm and doesn't seem to work as expected. Maybe the problem is in getting the vector as I said before

Comment: It might be useful to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication

Comment: I don't see the problem here.  Your definition is compatible with $\text{trace}(\hat x \hat y) = -2 x^T y$.  Just multiply out the left hand side in detail, and you will see that it is correct.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith the problem is that $-\frac{1}{2}tr[\hat{x}\hat{y}] = x^{T}y$ is still a matrix. But I need a vector. The solution in the paper is, to me, misleading. I don't need to demonstrate that $tr[\hat{x}\hat{y}] = -2x^{T}y$ but just how to get a vector from that matrix

Comment: $x^T y$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, which is interpreted as a scalar.

Comment: I know you made the question a long time ago. But why $e_{R}$ is a matrix? To me it should be a vector